# Border to edges of a div on hover with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way to create a border on hover for only edges of the div. Here is the basic layout of my grid created using bootstrap. here is my codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvxEYw

```
  <div class="product-grid col-md-4">
    <a class="preview" href="#">PREVIEW</a>
  </div>

.product-grid{
  margin:30px 0 0 30px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  height:300px;
  display:block;
}
.product-grid:hover{
  border:1px solid #000;
}
/* Preview */
.preview {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  right: 40px;
  top: 0;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 32px;
  background-color: #fe3;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  transition: .2s;
}

.product-grid:hover .preview {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 80px;
}
```

For clear understand I have attached a sample image below

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050006/css-border-on-corners-only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Achieving that kind of effect, is best possible if you use **CSS3**, and I've done it by using `<svg>` as:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
            <line class="top" x1="0" y1="0" x2="900" y2="0" />
            <line class="left" x1="0" y1="460" x2="0" y2="-920" />
            <line class="bottom" x1="300" y1="460" x2="-600" y2="460" />
            <line class="right" x1="300" y1="0" x2="300" y2="1380" />
</svg>
```

Here look into my [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/hvqyuau4), Hope you're looking something like this.
And it will do the trick for you.

Further customization is no big deal, just look into its *CSS* and you can changes it as per your requirement.

**Source**: [**tympanus**](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/02/26/creating-a-border-animation-effect-with-svg-and-css)

Answer (score 1):

please try this one sir:

```
#div1 {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}

#div2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    left: -2px;
    height: 84px;
    width: 84px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#div1:hover {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/3jo5btxd/36/)

Comment: I think you just copy pasted it. Same answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/26349998/3243201

Comment: yes I agree but that problrm i solve it right..@SrinivasPai

Comment: you have not solved it. you would have referred him and answered the question.